# Django Template Folder Naming

Tags: python, django, django-templates

## Preface

I have a Django project called `shopping_list` and an app in that project called `main` with this structure. the main page of the main app will use `main.html` as a template

```
.
├── main
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── create_product.html
│   │   └── main.html
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── shopping_list
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── templates
│   └── base.html
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

with all the templates in `main/templates` extending `base.html` in the base templates folder. I am aware that the templates folder in Django can be configured with adding

```py
...
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
...
```

to the `settings.py` file on the project folder. this will successfully connect all templates with no problem. However when I change the folder name to something else, i.e.

```py
...
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'somethingElse'],
...
```

and rename the folders accordingly,

```
.
├── main
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── somethingElse
│   │   ├── create_product.html
│   │   └── main.html
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── shopping_list
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── somethingElse
│   └── base.html
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

suddenly the project won't detect the templates under `main/somethingElse`. I'm trying to learn and teach Django to non-english speakers so renaming the folder from "templates" to something they would understand is logical.

## Question

Does django only accept the folder name "templates"? how can I change it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, Django looks for a "templates" directory in every installed app.  Visit [https://devdocs.io/django~4.2/intro/tutorial03](https://devdocs.io/django%7E4.2/intro/tutorial03)